# noVNC console on Openstack Dashboard is rendering garbled UI on RHEL7

Tags: python, vnc, libvirt, openstack, rhel7

I am running nova-compute on RHEL7. Openstack dashboard's noVNC console is rendering garbled UI for any instance having a UI console. Can somebody please help out? This is working just fine on RHEL65

[image: VM UI]

Comment: There is open issue on https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/issues/531 and the fix is available at https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/pull/532. Let us know if this works for you.